How do I make this statement pass Typecript rules?
I'm new to Typescript and am trying to add Typescript checking to an existing Pinia store in a Vue 3 project. All is going well except for a Javascript reduce function that Typescript is flagging but I don't pretend to understand what it is unhappy about.
Here is the Pinia store:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

import { getSystemLocaleName } from '@dnvgl/i18n';
import { useToast } from 'vue-toastification';
const toast = useToast();

type Transaction = {
    id: number;
    description: string;
    transactionType: string;
    amount: number;
}

export const useTestStore = defineStore('storeTest', {
    state: () => ({ 
        transactions:  [
             { "id": 9, "description": "Salary", "transactionType": "Income", "amount": 3000.00 },
             { "id": 27, "description": "Air Fare", "transactionType": "Expense", "amount": 700.00 },
             { "id": 6, "description": "Taxi", "transactionType": "Expense", "amount": 30.00 }
        ]
    }),
    actions: {
        addTransaction(newTransaction: Transaction) {
            
            /* Add the new transaction to the array in this store. */
            this.transactions.push(newTransaction)
            toast.success("Successfully added the transaction.", {timeout: 1000})

            /* Update the array in local storage to reflect the added transaction. */
            localStorage.setItem('transactions', JSON.stringify(this.transactions));
        },
        deleteTransaction(idOfTransactionToBeDeleted: number) {

            /* Find the transaction which is to be deleted via its Id. */
            const transactionToBeDeleted = this.transactions.find(e => e.id == idOfTransactionToBeDeleted);

            /* The value of transactionToBeDeleted will be undefined if no transaction exists with the 
               specified key. This could happen if another process deleted the transaction just before
               this user tried to do so. If that happens, notify the user. */
            if (typeof transactionToBeDeleted == 'undefined') {
                toast.error("The transaction with ID," + idOfTransactionToBeDeleted + ", does not exist.", {timeout: false});
                return;
            }

            /* Find the index of the transaction which is to be deleted. */
            const index: number = this.transactions.indexOf(transactionToBeDeleted);

            /* Delete the indicated transaction from the array. */
            this.transactions.splice(index, 1)
            toast.success("Successfully deleted the transaction with ID " + idOfTransactionToBeDeleted + ".", {timeout: 1000})

            /* Update the array in local storage to reflect the deleted transaction. */
            localStorage.setItem('transactions', JSON.stringify(this.transactions));
        }     
    },
    getters: {
        getNewId(): number {

            let newId = 0;
            if (this.transactions.length === 0) {
                newId = 1;
            } else {
                /* Use reduce() to find the transaction with the highest value of Id in the transactions array. */
                const transactionWithHighestId: Transaction = this.transactions.reduce((prev, current) => {
                    return (prev && prev.id > current.id) ? prev : current},0); //returns transaction unless array is empty, in which case 0 is returned
                const highestId = transactionWithHighestId.id; //get the Id of the transaction that has the highest Id
                newId = highestId + 1; //add 1 to the highest existing Id to get the Id of the new transaction
            }

            return newId;
        },
        getBalance(): number {
            return (this.getIncome - this.getExpense)
        },
        getIncome(): number {

            /* Use filter() to make a new array containing only Income transactions. */
            const incomeTransactions: Transaction[] = this.transactions.filter(transaction => transaction.transactionType === 'Income')

            /* Use reduce() to sum up the Income transactions. */
            const totalIncome = incomeTransactions.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.amount, 0)
            
            return totalIncome
        },

        getExpense(): number {

            /* Use filter() to make a new array containing only Expense transactions. */
            const expenseTransactions: Transaction[] = this.transactions.filter(transaction => transaction.transactionType === 'Expense')
        
            /* Use reduce() to sum up the Expense transactions. */
            const totalExpense = expenseTransactions.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.amount, 0)
            
            return totalExpense
        }
    }
})

The problem occurs in the getNewId() function; the Typescript error is ts(2769). The squiggly line runs from the second open bracket to the first open brace. There is a second squiggly line under the id in prev.id; the Typescript error is ts(2339).
Can anyone advise me on how to make those errors go away by writing proper Typescript code to prevent them (as opposed to disabling error flagging)?
Also, can anyone see where additional Typescript code is advisable to prevent potential errors?
Lastly, if I wanted to ensure that id was not just a number but an integer and that amount was not just a number but a decimal number, how would I do that?

Your transactionWithHighestId specifies a type annotation that directly contradicts your logic which can produce a number or an object depending on the length of the array. There are many solutions but I'd advise you take care of a 0 length array separately and simplify your reduce projection. Like transactions.reduce((p, c) => Math.max(p, c.id), 0). You could also Math.max(transactions.map(t => t.id)) and many other things

@AluanHaddad - Thank you! Yes, that makes perfect sense. I just removed the final ,0 from the expression and the errors went away. It was silly to include it in the first place since I was only executing the reduce() if the array had at least one transaction in it.
